# How do I convert asp:textbox to freetextbox

Tags: asp.net, freetextbox

I have an asp:TextBox that I need to convert to a FreeTextBox.  The following is my asp:TextBox aspx code:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="FTB" Namespace="FreeTextBoxControls" Assembly="FreeTextBox" %>

<asp:TextBox ID="tbxRiskDesc" runat="server" Width="90%" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="6" onblur="Resize(this);" onkeypress="Resize(this);" ></asp:TextBox>

<rad:RadSpell ID="spellRiskDesc" runat="server" Width="5px" ControlToCheck="tbxRiskDesc" WordIgnoreOptions="UPPERCASE" FragmentIgnoreOptions="EmailAddresses,Urls" DictionaryLanguage="en-AU" SupportedLanguages="en-AU,English" AllowAddCustom="true" DictionaryPath="~/RadControls/Spell/TDF/" SpellCheckProvider="EditDistanceProvider" EditDistance="2" ButtonType="ImageButton" />
```

The following code is in the aspx.cs code:

Page_Load:

```
tbxRiskDesc.Attributes.Add("onchange", "setDirty();");
```

Reset_Data:

```
SetTextCurrentValue(tbxRiskDesc, dtEditTable, "RiskDesc");
```

Clear_Data:

```
SetTextValue(tbxRiskDesc, "RISK TITLE & DESC.:");
```

When I replace the "asp:TextBox" code in the aspx file with the following, the code behind has errors and i dont know how to change the code for the FreeTextBox for the Page_Load, Reset_Data & Clear_Data sections.

```
<FTB:FreeTextBox ID="tbxRiskDesc" runat="server"></FTB:FreeTextBox>
```

The reason for the change over is because we need to allow the users to put bullet points and hyperlinks into the text boxes.

All help is appreciated.

Comment: What is FreeTextBox? Does it extend the asp textbox and does it have/support the same methods in any way?

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

- recommended: replace the textbox with RadEditor which has built-in integration with RadSpell
- use the RadSpell API to spellcheck the FreeTextBox control: You have to get a reference to the body element of the iframe content area of FreeTextBox. After that you can implement a custom text source similarly as it is done for RadEditor in the following forum thread: [Problem with spellcheck](http://www.telerik.com/forums/problem-with-spellcheck).

Using the RadEditor's get_contentAreaElement() method you can get a reference to RadEditor's iframe content area element and after that to get a reference to the body tag of the iframe:

var editorSource = $find('RadEditor1').get_contentAreaElement().contentWindow.document.body;

You should see in the FreeTextBox documentation or forums how to get a reference to the body element and update the above line in the provided in the forum article  custom text source code.